# Having guests for a Friday mid-day or afternoon meal?

Tags: meal-seudah, hachnasat-orchim-guests, erev-shabbat

Are there any rules regarding having a guest on a Friday afternoon? Let's say you want to have a friend or family member over for a meal, and Friday is the only day that works, and evening (that is, Shabbat dinner) will not work.

Is it permitted to have a guest at this time (mid-day or afternoon on Friday)? Is it ever permitted to serve dishes that one will also serve for Shabbat? I assume it is forbidden to eat from dishes prepared for Shabbat before Shabbat (other than tasting), but perhaps it is permitted under some circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's recommended to have a guest or a meal at that time, but it doesn't seem that it is prohibited, as Rabban Gamliel and R' Yose had a meal together on erev Shabbos ([Pesachim 100b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=100b&format=pdf)), and they even went into Shabbos:

> מעשה ברשב"ג [ורבי יהודה] ורבי יוסי שהיו מסובין בעכו וקדש עליהם היום

Any meal at this time should not be larger than your regular meals, as it is prohibited to have an abnormal meal on *erev Shabbos* ([Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 249:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1433)).

Comment: "Recommended..." I'm pretty sure it isn't recommended. See Shulchan Aruch O.C. 249:2